# PHP Dynamic Content Page with Loginsystem

Tags: php

I'm pretty new to programming and gotta do a project for school. My task is to wrinte a ticketsystem with login etc. in PHP.

Since my groupmates aren't to helpful at all i decided to just code the loginsystem and create a .php which loads content dynamicly.

For normal links things went smooth so far but the loginsystem + the dynamic system gives me headache already.

Whenever i hit the login button (even when I don't enter any logindata at all) I endup in the frontpage(home.php) with the header tellin me that I'm on the "user.php".

I don't get any errors or anything, there seems to be just soem logical errors which i don't get :-(

can anybody help me with this?

http://pastebin.com/5XMSje07

Comment: Please add the code to you question and format it correctly.

Comment: There's too much code there. You need to narrow it down much further than that for this to be a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add exit() under all of your header() redirects
2. What's your directory structure looking like?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't have a check for empty fields when the post comes in. There should be something along the lines of the following in your login function when the post is read in:

```
if($_POST['Login'] == null || $_POST['Password'] == null)
{
   return false;
}
else
{
   //do the login check with the sql call to match username and pw
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirects should be used more sparingly than you appear to have done

In your login script, you have:

```
if(!isset($usergroup))
{      
    login();       
} else {
    logout($usergroup);
}
```

This is all very well if you assigned $usergroup from a $SESSION value, which you haven't done. This page will therefore always show the login form.

```
$usergroup = $_SESSION['user'];
```

would be a start.

You also have multiple session_start calls, as it says in Highlander, "There can be only one".

Your code to detect whether someone has posted data to your script is inside the functions and probably should be inside the above test. Something like...

```
if (!isset($usergroup)) {
   // have we recieved post data to login, if logged in set usergroup)
   // if we have not logged in, show the login form
}
if (isset($usergroup) {
   // show the logout form
}
```